# SPA MVC Routing Mirroring no Controller in URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I like to route routes directly to the index controller. I do this to ge 404 responses for SEO. How can i route the controller with a different url name

```
// Map to www.mydomain.com
       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: indexCtrl);
// Map to www.mydomain.com/services
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Services",
            url: "services",
            defaults: indexCtrl);
```

Comment: you need to clarify your question a little more. Also check out Google's SEP specification https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification and a library I wrote to help with SPAs, https://github.com/docluv/SPAHelper

Comment: For dead pages google get an 404 Page not found from the backend. This is not possible by serving just an single page over the mvc and URLs without hashbangs.

Comment: Actually, it is. You do need to build intelligence in your server to pick these up. You need a 301 redirect module in place to redirect from legacy URLs to new, modern application SPAs.